# how to send emails to an array off address from prepared statement

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, email

I'm new fairly new to php and prepared statements. I have been asked to develop an email script that sends reminder emails to unregistered users.

Basically the code is in wordpress so it needs to use the $wpdb class. However I am having trouble extracting the email addresses from an array and then send them using the mail function. It is only sending to 1 email address.

```
$query =  $wpdb->get_results("select contact_name, email_address, password from user where activation_token is NULL");

foreach ($query as $result ) {      
$recipients = $result->email_address;   
        }   


if(!empty($query)) {
    $boundary = uniqid('np');
    $from = 'mydomain';

    //headers - specify your from email address and name here
    //and specify the boundary for the email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ". $from ." \r\n";
    $headers .= "To: ".$email."\r\n";
            if (isset($bcc)) {
                $headers .= "Bcc: ".$bcc. "\r\n";
            }
    $headers .= "To: ".$recipient."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";

    //here is the content body
    $message = "This is a MIME encoded message.";
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

    //Plain text body
    $message .= $text_msg;
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

    //Html body
    $message .= $html_msg;
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

    $to = $name; 
    $subject = "E-mail subject";
    $headers .= 'BCC: ' .$recipients. "\r\n";

    //error_log($message);
    //error_log($headers);

mail('', $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'emails have been sent';


}else{

    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with `mail()`. it doesn't care WHERE you get the email addresses from. So either you're calling the mail() function wrong, or you're not retrieving the email addresses properly. And for this sort of thing, you really should be using PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. They make it far easier to sent "complicated" emails.

Comment: I think this line has something to do with it `if (isset($bcc)) {
                $headers .= "Bcc: ".$bcc. "\r\n";
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no WordPress expert but this looks like a great way of converting a large array of information to ONE bit of information.

```
foreach ($query as $result ) {      
    $recipients = $result->email_address;   
}
```

This will only remember the last email address in `$recipients`

Also the first parameter of the `mail()` function is the To address and you are entering `''` i.e. `mail('', $subject, $message, $headers);`

I guess you actually want to do something like this

```
$query =  $wpdb->get_results("select contact_name, email_address, password from user where activation_token is NULL");

foreach ($query as $result ) {      

    $boundary = uniqid('np');
    $from = 'mydomain';

    //headers - specify your from email address and name here
    //and specify the boundary for the email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ". $from ." \r\n";
    if (isset($bcc)) {
       $headers .= "Bcc: ".$bcc. "\r\n";
    }
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";

    //here is the content body
    $message = "This is a MIME encoded message.";
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

    //Plain text body
    $message .= $text_msg;
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

    //Html body
    $message .= $html_msg;
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

    $to = $name; 
    $subject = "E-mail subject";
    $headers .= 'BCC: ' .$recipients. "\r\n";

    //error_log($message);
    //error_log($headers);

    if ( mail($result->email_address, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
        echo 'emails have been sent';
    } else {
        echo 'emailing failed';
    }
}
```